# Getting error when save an item line in Sales Order in Suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to update the line level information of sales order. When I tried to save the record I am getting the below error.

{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"RCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED","message":"Record has been changed"....

Code I tried to save the record is

```
var soItemNumLines = soRecord.getLineCount({
            sublistId: "item"
        });
for (var z = 0; z < soItemNumLines ; z++) {
   soRecord.selectLine({
    sublistId: "item",
    line: z
    });
   soRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: "item",
    fieldId: CUSTCOL_CANCEL_REASON_FIELD,
    value: cancel_reason_code
    });
   soRecord.commitLine({
    sublistId: "item"
    });
 }
 soRecord.save();
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to do this in the before submit portion of a user event script, and that would cause the problem. Just take out the soRecord.save(). If not, can you provide more context?

Comment: Yes, the code is branching out based on different conditions and updating different columns of the sublist. And, the save api is called in afterSubmit event.

Comment: Can you move it to the beforeSubmit event and remove the soRecord.save()? Otherwise, you will have to reload the record before you can manipulate and save it.

Comment: Ok @NathanSutherland, thanks for the suggestion. I created a different object for the record and saved that record